# if I give "no" as a response to any_toppings it asks what kind even though I said no

Tags: python-3.x

```
favorite = input('What is your favorite kind of ice cream? ')

print(f'{favorite} is my favorite too!')

any_toppings = input('Do you put any kind of toppings on top? ')
print(any_toppings)

kind_of_toppings = input('Nice What kind? ')

if any_toppings.lower() == 'yes':
    print(kind_of_toppings)
elif any_toppings.lower() == 'no':
    print(" yea it is amazing by it's self!")
else:
    print('sorry i didnt catch that, try again')
    print(any_toppings)
```

Comment: Yes. The lines of code are executed in the order they're written in.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have the input in the code, and it does not consider the `if any_toppings.lower() == 'yes'` when asking you for the input for `kind_of_toppings = input('Nice What kind? ')`, it will run no matter what your input to `any_toppings` is so for your code you must move the input for `kind_of_topping` inside the if statement. It would look like:

```
favorite = input('What is your favorite kind of ice cream? ')

print(f'{favorite} is my favorite too!')

any_toppings = input('Do you put any kind of toppings on top? ')
print(any_toppings)

if any_toppings.lower() == 'yes':
    kind_of_toppings = input('Nice What kind? ')
    print(kind_of_toppings)
elif any_toppings.lower() == 'no':
    print(" yea it is amazing by it's self!")
else:
    print('sorry i didnt catch that, try again')
    print(any_toppings)
```

Comment: ohhh ok that makes sense thanks for the help!